# Apk only runs in debug mode in android studio and either not installed or crashes immediately on opening of app when installed through app on phone

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have build an app its running fine on debug mode of phone but when installing .apk externally to phone its either saying not installed or frequently in some its installing and as soon as opened crashes.
I tried all version fix and all.

android manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launch"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/launch"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".Launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginViaFb"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login_via_fb"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Dashboard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What android version you are using in your phone and what is the `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` of your app?

Comment: android phone versions is 7.0 and 5.0                               
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
       
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: Try to provide both `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 26 and see if it works